# htaccess redirect urls without extention to one with .php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have lots of urls (3000) without an extension so require a rule to redirect them to the same URL but with .php added to the end.

I have managed to suss out a rewrite rule but I want a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: So you want to show `example.com/file.php` to show in browser instead of `example.com/file`?

Comment: You can just add `R=301` in `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: "I have lots of **files** (3000) without an extension" - I assume you mean URLs?!

Answer (score 0):

And the answers thanks to anubhava is:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```